# How to obtain foreign key field name in post method?

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have an API which I pass some sample data. I am overwriting the post method by copying the Queryset so I can manipulate the output data. I would like to access the value of a foreign key relationship but I can only access the foreign key itself.

Like so:

```
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data_request = request.data
        data_request = data_request.copy()

        machine_na = data_request.__getitem__('project')
        ##this gives me the id of the foreign key
        data_request.__setitem__('project', str('my value'))

        return Response(data_request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now that works. But I can't access the name of the foreign key.

My models as Foreign Keys:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    machine_name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.machine_name


class Project(models.Model):
    project_name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

My model that refers to the others:

```
class Simulation(models.Model):
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    machine                 = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    project
```

I hope I am clear enough. I would like to access the specific name of, for example, foreign key 2.

calling 'project.project_name' doesn't work and everything else I tried also not.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the project object using the key and then get the name from the object.

```
    project=Project.objects.get(id=int(self.request.POST['project']))
    machine_na = project.project_name
```

Comment: That is golden my friend!! Thank you very much, it works perfectly. If you like to improve your answer, there is a missing closing bracket in the first line.